# asp .net RowDataBound RSS

Tags: asp.net, rowdatabound

i want a RowDataBound if the previous date in filed check in  not found be red color

like  the date 10/10/2014 not found so 10/11/214 be red and how can i edit the date to be dd/mm/yyyy

thanks for your help .

```
Name        Checkin           Checkout              Branch
450 10/6/2014 9:13:38 AM    10/6/2014 6:01:50 PM    branch0
450 10/7/2014 9:16:34 AM    10/7/2014 6:44:21 PM    branch0
450 10/8/2014 9:11:53 AM                            branch0
450 10/8/2014 6:03:25 PM                            branch0
450 10/11/2014 9:17:33 AM   10/11/2014 6:29:16 PM   branch0 (red color )
450 10/11/2014 4:50:42 PM                           branch0
450 10/12/2014 9:09:38 AM                           branch0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Protected Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
        If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

            If e.Row.RowIndex <> 0 Then
                Dim dt1 As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(Me.GridView1.Rows(e.Row.RowIndex - 1).Cells(1).Text, New CultureInfo("en-GB"))
                Dim dt2 As DateTime = Convert.ToDateTime(e.Row.Cells(1).Text, New CultureInfo("en-GB"))
                Dim timeSpan As TimeSpan = dt2.Subtract(dt1)
                If timeSpan.TotalHours > 24 Then
                    e.Row.BackColor = Color.Red
                End If
            End If
        End If

End Sub
```